# Elastic search case insensitive

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, spring-data

I have the following annotation based elastic search configuration, I've set the index not to be analyzed because I don't want these fields to be tokenized:

```
    @Document(indexName = "abc", type = "efg")
    public class ResourceElasticSearch {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field(type = FieldType.String, index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed)
    private String name;
    @Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true)
    private List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();
    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private String clientId;
    @Field(type = FieldType.String, index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed)
    private String virtualPath;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Date)
    private Date lastModifiedTime;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Date)
    private Date lastQueryTime;
    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private String modificationId;
    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private String realPath;
    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private String extension;
    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private ResourceType type;
```

Is it possible by using annotations to make the searches on the name, virtualPath and tags to be case-insensitive?
The search looks like this, search by wildcard is required:

```
private QueryBuilder getQueryBuilderForSearch(SearchCriteria criteria) {
    String virtualPath = criteria.getPath();

    return boolQuery()
            .must(wildcardQuery("virtualPath", virtualPath))
            .must(wildcardQuery("name", criteria.getName()));
}
```

Comment: Not really possible. Is not about Spring Data configuration, it's about Elasticsearch itself. You indexed data as not_analyzed and it will stay that way. Also, if you wanted case insensitive data why not indexing with `keyword` analyzer combined with a `lowercase` token filter?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think that's exactly what I need.

Comment: Andrei can you please post your reply as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really possible what you want to do and it's not about Spring Data configuration, it's about Elasticsearch itself: you indexed data as `not_analyzed` and it will stay that way.

Also, if you wanted case insensitive data I suggest indexing with [`keyword` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) combined with a [`lowercase` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html).

Answer (score 1):

I've found something based on Andrei Stefan's suggestion which has a similar result to using the annotations:

```
    @Bean
    public Client client() throws IOException {
    TransportClient client = new TransportClient();
    TransportAddress address = new InetSocketTransportAddress(env.getProperty("elasticsearch.host"), Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("elasticsearch.port")));
    client.addTransportAddress(address);

    XContentBuilder settingsBuilder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
            .startObject()
            .startObject("analysis")
            .startObject("analyzer")
            .startObject("keyword")
            .field("tokenizer", "keyword")
            .array("filter", "lowercase")
            .endObject()
            .endObject()
            .endObject()
            .endObject();
    if (!client.admin().indices().prepareExists("abc").execute().actionGet().isExists()) {
        client.admin().indices().prepareCreate("abc").setSettings(settingsBuilder).get();
    }
       return client;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `@Setting`, which consumes file path, after `@Document`, settings file should contain json like this:
`{"analysis":{"analyzer":{"case_insensitive":{"type":"custom","tokenizer":"whitespace","char_filter":["html_strip"],"filter":["lowercase","asciifolding"]}}}}`
and field annotation with analyzer `@Field(type = FieldType.Keyword, analyzer = "case_insensitive")`